# How do I keep my custom token secure?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, erc-20, etherscan, tokenomics

I am planning to launch my custom token on polygon. But little skeptical about. After the deployment of erc20, token comes to my account.

But it feels little insecure to keep all coins on an account as account can be lost or hacked?

What are some possible ways to secure my coins?

I am a blockchain new kid. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some possible security measures (they can also be combined):

1. First and foremost, human is typically the weakest link in any security. So do your research and be careful when doing stuff online
2. Buy a hardware wallet. This helps avoid certain types of attacks
3. Use a multi-signature wallet. This also helps to avoid certain types of attacks

On the other hand, you should also remember that your tokens are worthless in the beginning. So, even if someone steals your tokens, they'd get nothing of value. The tokens start to get value only when the tokens get usage and people want to pay for them. So the more valuable they are, the better protection you should have.